# Trying to type a string breaks folding

Tags: c, vim

I want to demonstrate my issue with an example. 
Let's say I'm working on the following code and the # represents the cursor.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* str = #;
    if (argc == 1) {
        // this is folded
    }
}
```

Let's say I'm about to add an empty string i.e just 2 quotation marks `""`.  When I type the first " the string is unclosed and vim thinks the string goes all the way until EOF. That breaks all foldings along the path.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* str = "#;
    if (argc == 1) {
        // this is now temporarily in string so the fold breaks
    }
}
```

Now when I type another " a second later, the string is now closed, but everything which was folded up until EOF is now open.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char* str = ""#;
    if (argc == 1) {
        // this now open
    }
}
```

How do I prevent this from happening?
I use `vim 7.4` and I use `set foldmethod=syntax` as my fold method.